# Hosting public SPARQL endpoint in server

Tags: linux, server, sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have a server with storage of 50 GB, I wanted to install Jena Fueski/Virtuoso server in my own server. So that I can run the SPARQL endpoint from the browser.

How can I install the Jena Fueski/Virtuoso server?

Comment: by follwing their documentation I'd say? Seriously, https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/ and http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/ch-installation/

Comment: Thanks, but once the server is installed, how would I access the interface? Our server is linked with a domain name, do I need to configure something to access by domain name? I mean when I install the server in MAC/Widows we can use on browser.

Comment: not sure what you mean, the interface is available via standard HTTP protocol. On your machine it's `localhost` with some port, if you want to make it available from other machines, you have to forward the port.